# How can I access AWS iot.describeCertificate() inside lambda with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, async-await, certificate, aws-iot

I need to retrieve an IoT-certificate status using a lambda function with NodeJS.
Following the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Iot.html#describeCertificate-property) I should use `describeCertificate()` to accomplish this task.

This is the code I have so far (using for testes):

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const iot = new AWS.Iot()
let cert = {}

async function descCert (params) {

  console.log("start descCert")
  console.log("params")
  console.log(params)

  await iot.describeCertificate(params, function(err, data) {
    console.log('describeCertificate - Fn')
    if (err) {
      console.log('describeCertificate - Error')
      console.log(err, err.stack)
    }else{
      console.log('describeCertificate - data')
      cert = data
      console.log(data)
    }
    console.log("end describeCertificate - Fn")
  })

  console.log("end descCert")
}

module.exports.testFn = async (event, context, callback) => { 

    var zzz = {
        certificateId: 'xxxx8c0891f8xxxxxx'
    }
    await descCert(zzz)
    console.log("after descCert")
    console.log(cert)

...
}
```

My guess is that I am not accessing the function `await iot.describeCertificate( ...` since I cant see the logs in `CloudWatch`.

I should receive this sequence:

1. start descCert
2. params
3. {certificateId: 'xxxx8c0891f8xxxxxx'}
4. describeCertificate - Fn
5. Or describeCertificate - Error Or describeCertificate - data
6. actual data response
7. end describeCertificate - Fn
8. end descCert
9. after descCert
10. actual data response

But this is what I am getting:

1. start descCert
2. params
3. {certificateId: 'xxxx8c0891f8xxxxxx'}
4. (8) end descCert
5. (9) after descCert
6. (10) os dados mesmo //{}

I can't see the steps 4-7 in the logs INFO. So the conclusion is the FUnctions is not being called.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

For accessing IoT core service (or any other services) you should give the Lambda function the corresponding RIGHT accesses to that service. To do that you can go to IAM -> Roles and add the corresponding policy to the role attached to your Lambda function.

You may add inline policy to the corresponding lambda-role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iot:DescribeCertificate",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:*:*:cert/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

It is better to change the `Resource` to your corresponding `arn`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

async function get_certificate_status(iot, params) {
    try {
        const data = await iot.describeCertificate(params).promise();
        return data.certificateDescription.status;
    } catch(e) {
        throw new Error(e.message);  
    }
}

exports.handler = async function(event, context, callback) {
    var iot = new AWS.Iot({'region': <region>, apiVersion: '2015-05-28'});        
    var params = { certificateId: <certificateId> };
    
    var cert_status = await get_certificate_status(iot, params);
    console.log("STATUS: " + cert_status);
}
```